# thread safe LinkedHashMap without Collections.synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, concurrency, oracle-maf

I am using a LinkedHashMap and the environment is multi threaded so this structure needs to be thread safe. During specific events I need to read the entire map push to db and clear all.

Most of time only writes happen to this map. This map has a limit 50 entries.

I am using Oracle MAF and it does not have Collections.syncronizedMap available. So, what are things I need to put in synchronized blocks to make sure writing and reading doesn't hit me concurrentModificationException etc

Few requirements:

1. I need to behave it like a circular queue so Overriding removeEldestEntry method of the LinkedHashMap.
2. I need to preserve the order

Comment: Every time you call a method on your hasmap, like `get` or `put`, you need to surround it with synchronization. If you have multiple calls in a row, you can surround them all with one synchronization. Post some of your code.

Comment: don's synchronized the map while writing to db. make a copy (in synchronized{}), write the copy to db.

Comment: what benefit do you see? my map can hold max 50 entries. and i believe making a copy would take the same time as iterating over it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, what are things I need to put in synchronized blocks to make sure writing and reading doesn't hit me concurrentModificationException etc

Everything method call should be in a synchronized block.

The tricky one being the use of an Iterator, as you have to hold the lock for the life of the Iterator. e.g.

```
// pre Java 5.0 code
synchronized(map) { // the lock has to be held for the whole loop.
    for(Iterator iter = map.entrySet().iterator(); iter.hashNext(); ) {
         Map.Entry entry = iter.next();
         String key = (String) entry.getKey();
         MyType value = (MyType) entry.getValue();
         // do something with key and value.
    }
}
```

Comment: so i am iterating like

            if(diagMap != null && diagMap.size() > 0){
                Set<Date> keys = diagMap.keySet();

                for (Date key : keys) {
                    String value = diagMap.get(key);
                    dPath.append(key).append(DELIM).append(value);
                }
            }

wouldn't it release iterator after the for loop?

Answer (score 3):

Most `LinkedHashMap` operations require `synchronization` in a multi-threaded environment, even the ones that look pure like `get(key)`, `get(key)` actually mutates some internal nodes. The easiest you could do is using `Collections.synchronizedMap`.

```
Map<K,V> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<>());
```

Now if it is not available, you can easily add it, as it is just a simple `decorator` around map that `synchronize` all operation.

```
class SyncMap<T,U> implements Map<T,U>{
  SyncMap<T,U>(LinkedHashMap<T,U> map){
   ..
  }
  public synchronized U get(T t){
    ..
  }
}
```

Comment: do i need to do that for all the LinkedHashMap operations?

Comment: ok i think then its better to use synchronized block around gets and puts

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a java version 1.5 or newer you can use  [`java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

This is the most efficient implementation of a Map to use in a multithread environment.

It adds also some method like `putIfAbsent` very useful for atomic operations on the map.

From java doc:

> Retrieval operations (including get) **generally do not block**, so may
>   overlap with update operations (including put and remove). Retrievals
>   reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations
>   holding upon their onset. **For aggregate operations** such as putAll and
>   **clear**, **concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of** **only**
>   **some entries**

So verify is this is the behaviour you expect from your class.

---

If your map has only 50 records and needs to be used as a circular Queue why you use a Map? Is not better to use one of the Queue implementations?

---

If you need to use a LinkedHashMap use the following:

```
Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap());
```

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) of `LinkedHashMap`:

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads
>   access a linked hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads
>   modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally.
>   This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that
>   naturally encapsulates the map. If no such object exists, the map
>   should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedMap method. This
>   is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized
>   access to the map:
>
> ```
>  Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap(...));
> ```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Comment: i believe it doesn't support overriding removeEldestEntry method to make it behave like a circular queue

Comment: As i said in my post, I do not have  Collections.synchronizedMap available in my env which uses a restricted jdk profile

Comment: So I imagine that you can only surround your code with synchronized or use a custom data structure