# When multiple threads are writing to one LinkedHashMap, only one key value pair is retained added by last thread

Tags: multithreading

I have a scenario When multiple threads are writing to one LinkedHashMap, on iterating through Map after execution is completed **only one key value pair is retained added by last thread.**

Please advice me on this.

Thanks

Comment: what else do you expect from an unsafe/not synchronized `LinkedHashMap`? Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321481/thread-safe-linkedhashmap-without-collections-synchronized)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the `LinkedHashMap` implementation is not `synchronized`. If multiple threads access a linked hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be `synchronized` externally. This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object. If no such object exists, the `map` should be "wrapped" using the `Collections.synchronizedMap` method. This is best done at creation time, to prevent accidental unsynchronized access to the map:

```
Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap(...));
```